# Using 3rd Party Java Libraries on JSP

Tags: jsp, libraries, jspinclude, java

How can I use 3rd party libraries like [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) on JSP?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit sick, but can you not just inline the appropriate Java in your JSP?

```
<%
   // This should really be in a servlet
   // Twitter4J code from their example 
   Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
   List<Status> statuses = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
   System.out.println("Showing friends timeline.");
   for (Status status : statuses) {
       System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                        status.getText());
   }
%>
```

Make sure that the Twitter4J jar and all its dependencies are in your WEB-INF/lib/ folder. Then, give some serious thought to not doing this in a JSP if at all possible!

Comment: Why don't you just answer "use a servlet" ans show a servlet example then?

Comment: As the user asked for it as a JSP, I'm guessing they had a strong reason for not wanting to do it as a servlet!